# Visual Studio sometimes doesn't stick to the theme

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2022 on Windows 10. I have it set to use the Dark theme. But sometimes--I think it's specifically when I've rebooted the computer--when I open VS, the editor panes will all have a white background, even though all the other panes remain dark. When I change the theme to something else and then switch it back to Dark, everything's as it should be. This problem arose only a few weeks ago. Is this a known issue? Is there a fix?